# I'm trying to make my image move using KeyListener but it's giving me an error?

Tags: java, image, keyboard, actionlistener, keylistener

I'm trying to make Boy1 move but in the second class I'm getting redlines under setX. Anyone know what's wrong?

First Class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y = 0, velx =0, vely =0;

    public MyGame() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x,y,50,30);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(x < 0)
        {
            velx=0;
            x = 0;  
        }

        if(x > 530)
        {
            velx=0;
            x = 530;    
        }

        if(y < 0)
        {
            vely=0;
            y = 0;  
        }

        if(y > 330)
        {
            vely=0;
            y = 330;    
        }

        x += velx;
        y += vely;
        repaint();
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
            vely = 1;
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            vely = -1;
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            vely = 0;
            velx = -1;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            vely = 0;
            velx = 1;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        velx=0;
        vely=0;
    }


    public static void main (String arge[]){

        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        MyGame s = new MyGame();
        f.add(s);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Problem is with this last class. Perhaps it needs to be KeyAdapter? But I tried that and seems like that totally doesn't work.

Comment: `but in the second class I'm getting redlines under setX.` - Did you create a `setX(...)` method?

Comment: thanks but I totally went another way. Much simpler way. If you wanna see it you can look at my last post.

Comment: reverting back to using a Applet which is old outdated technology does not make it a simpler way. You will need to unlearn everything you are doing with the applet in order to learn how to use Swing properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler is flagging you for a reason -- you're trying to call methods on a variable as if it were a variable that the class contains when it isn't -- it's held by a different class. And this isn't Kosher in Java.

What you should do is give the class that holds the variable public methods that outside classes can call and that will allow outside classes to be able to move the label. Then give your control object (the listener) an instance of the class that has these methods.

As an aside, you're usually better off using Key Bindings and not using a KeyListener.

---

I can give you an example of code that uses Key Bindings to move a JLabel around a JPanel:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.EnumMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AnimateExample extends JPanel {
   public static final String DUKE_IMG_PATH = // https://duke.kenai.com/iconSized/duke.gif
         "https://duke.kenai.com/iconSized/duke4.gif";
   private static final int PREF_W = 800;
   private static final int PREF_H = 800;
   private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 20;
   private static final String KEY_DOWN = "key down";
   private static final String KEY_RELEASE = "key release";
   public static final int TRANSLATE_SCALE = 3;
   private static final String BACKGROUND_STRING = "Use Arrow Keys to Move Image";
   private static final Font BG_STRING_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF,
         Font.BOLD, 32);
   private EnumMap<Direction, Boolean> dirMap = 
         new EnumMap<AnimateExample.Direction, Boolean>(Direction.class);
   private BufferedImage image = null;
   private int imgX = 0;
   private int imgY = 0;
   private int bgStringX; 
   private int bgStringY; 

   public AnimateExample() {
      for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
         dirMap.put(dir, Boolean.FALSE);
      }
      try {
         URL imgUrl = new URL(DUKE_IMG_PATH);
         image = ImageIO.read(imgUrl);
         Icon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, icon);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

      new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();

      // here we set up our key bindings
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(condition);
      ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();
      for (final Direction dir : Direction.values()) {

         // for the key down key stroke
         KeyStroke keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(dir.getKeyCode(), 0,
               false);
         inputMap.put(keyStroke, dir.name() + KEY_DOWN);
         actionMap.put(dir.name() + KEY_DOWN, new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               dirMap.put(dir, true);
            }
         });

         // for the key release key stroke
         keyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(dir.getKeyCode(), 0, true);
         inputMap.put(keyStroke, dir.name() + KEY_RELEASE);
         actionMap.put(dir.name() + KEY_RELEASE, new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
               dirMap.put(dir, false);
            }
         });
      }

      FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(BG_STRING_FONT);
      int w = fontMetrics.stringWidth(BACKGROUND_STRING);
      int h = fontMetrics.getHeight();

      bgStringX = (PREF_W - w) / 2;
      bgStringY = (PREF_H - h) / 2;
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
      g.setFont(BG_STRING_FONT);
      g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g.drawString(BACKGROUND_STRING, bgStringX, bgStringY);

      if (image != null) {
         g.drawImage(image, imgX, imgY, this);
      }
   }

   private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
      public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
         for (Direction dir : Direction.values()) {
            if (dirMap.get(dir)) {
               imgX += dir.getX() * TRANSLATE_SCALE;
               imgY += dir.getY() * TRANSLATE_SCALE;
            }
         }
         repaint();
      };
   }

   enum Direction {
      Up(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0, -1), Down(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0, 1), Left(
            KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, -1, 0), Right(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 1, 0);

      private int keyCode;
      private int x;
      private int y;

      private Direction(int keyCode, int x, int y) {
         this.keyCode = keyCode;
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
      }

      public int getKeyCode() {
         return keyCode;
      }

      public int getX() {
         return x;
      }

      public int getY() {
         return y;
      }

   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      AnimateExample mainPanel = new AnimateExample();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("Animate Example");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: how do I make public methods? is there a link you can give me?

Comment: @Renox: [Java Links](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info), [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), [The Really Big Index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reallybigindex.html), [Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html).

Comment: just to make sure, are methods the imports up there?

Comment: @Renox: ??? you don't know what methods are? Please read the tutorials, especially the methods section.

Comment: Alright so method is essentially referred to a chuck of code? correct me if i'm wrong. But isn't this already public? Which method isn't public?

Comment: @Renox: you need to pass an instance of the Boy class into your InputKeyEvents class and assign it to a Boy variable. You need to **create** a new public method for the Boy class that your InputKeyEvents can call when it wants to change the state of your Boy class.

Comment: oh alright that makes a lot more sense. Let me see what I can do

Comment: can you give me a hint on what to do? these tutorials make no sense

Comment: @Renox: I can show you code that I've created for another question that moves a JLabel around with Key Bindings.

Comment: okay I think I fixed the problem by kinda going around it, i removed the third class and just implemented the Key listener to the boy class. Now theres an error on setX. is this fine?